# What does this do?

Tags: javascript

I found this. What does it do?

```
function G(a, b) {
  var c = function() { };
  c.prototype = b.prototype;
  a.T = b.prototype;
  a.prototype = new c;
}
```

- It looks very similar to [Crockford's Prototypal Inheritance in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html).
- Stackoverflow: [What is happening in Crockford’s object creation technique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766057/what-is-happening-in-crockfords-object-creation-technique).

Comment: I guess what you're asking is "why would anyone do this?", because other than answering "to confuse people", I don't have anything for you.

Comment: Where did you find this? The `T` property being set is not typical of any pattern I have seen regarding prototypical inheritance.
But what I believe this might be is having the constructor inherited as well as the prototype chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks similar to the Crockford's `Object.create` method, but this function is used to "setup" constructors.

It accepts two constructors as arguments, and it setups the `prototype` of the first one.

Let me rename the cryptic variable names:

```
function G(sub, super) {
  var F = function() { };
  F.prototype = super.prototype;
  sub.superLink = super.prototype;
  sub.prototype = new F();
}

function Super () {
  //...
}
Super.prototype.member1 = 'superMember1';

function Sub() {
  this.member2 = 'subMember2';
}

G(Sub, Super);

new Sub(); // Object { member2="subMember2",  member1="superMember1"}
```

**Edit:** The `T` property is simply used to know what is the "super" constructor of the sub one, I've seen this pattern on other places, like in the book *Pro JavaScript Design Patterns* ([page 43](http://books.google.com/books?id=za3vlnlWxb0C&lpg=PP1&dq=Pro%20JavaScript%20Design%20Patterns&pg=PA43#v=onepage&q&f=false)), with some additions, to prevent the `constructor` property to point to the wrong object:

```
function extend(subClass, superClass) {
    var F = function() {};
    F.prototype = superClass.prototype;
    subClass.prototype = new F();
    subClass.prototype.constructor = subClass;

    subClass.superclass = superClass.prototype;
    if(superClass.prototype.constructor == Object.prototype.constructor) {
        superClass.prototype.constructor = superClass;
    }
}
```

See also:

- [JavaScript inheritance extend function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686258/javascript-inheritance-extend-function)

Comment: I don't think its that simple, the `T` property is used in some way not clear by the question. Also, the result from your answer can be reached by just setting `Sub.prototype = Super.prototype`

Comment: @Sean Not quite. By doing that, if you add a member to `Sub.prototype` you will also add a member to `Super.prototype`.

Comment: @CMS I think it is worth to note that `member2` will be on the prototype chain of `new Sub()` and not on `new Sub()` itself.

Comment: @Pablo, not quite, `member2` is an own property, e.g. `new Sub().hasOwnProperty('member2'); // true`

Comment: @Sean, the purpose of `T` is for *knowing* from which constructor another was extended, check this pattern [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=za3vlnlWxb0C&lpg=PP1&dq=Pro%20JavaScript%20Design%20Patterns&pg=PA43#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: @CMS Thats what I thought from the start. 
But the `G` function does not support subclasses with a separate prototype, so I fail to see the usecase for this method, it pretty much just copies the prototype from one function to another..

Comment: @CMS Oh sorry, I meant `member1` from `Super.prototype`

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it gives you the ability to pass in a function, make changes to it, and then pass it back - a.prototype is a new instantiated copy of it.  There are examples on the net using this type of code for "getting" and "setting".