# JavaScript Inheritance question

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, extend

This is the extend function from the book "Pro JavaScript Design Patterns"

```
function extend(subClass, superClass) {
    var F = function() {};
    F.prototype = superClass.prototype;
    subClass.prototype = new F();
    subClass.prototype.constructor = subClass;
    subClass.superclass = superClass.prototype;
    if(superClass.prototype.constructor == Object.prototype.constructor) {
       superClass.prototype.constructor = superClass;
    }
}
```

I have problems with the first 3 lines... It creates an empty function and then it sets the F.prototype to superClass.prototype which means (for 2 new constructor functions e.g. foo, bar and foo extends bar) that F.prototype will have a constructor property: bar and **proto** :Object, or not? 
And on line 3: subClass.prototype = new F(); happens something that I cannot understand.. Why the inheritance happens here when F's [[Prototype]] is Object?

---

What are the differences between the first 3 lines and

```
subClass.prototype = new superClass();
```

when the code executes? I mean how The first does the same as the second one.

---

Just to add there is a call to the superClass constructor in the subClass.
The call is "className".superclass.constructor.call(this);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've got constructors:

`F` , `Super` & `Sub`.

We've got objects `f` , `super`, & `sub` that are made using said constructors.

i.e. `f = new F` , `super = new Super` , `sub = new Sub`

We know `f.__proto__ === super.__proto__ === Super.prototype` from line 2

From line 3 we can see that `sub.__proto__ === f` & `sub.__proto__.__proto__ === Super.prototype`

Also we have `Sub.superClass === Super.prototype` from line 5.

and from line 4 & 6 we can say that `sub.constructor === Sub` & `super.constructor === Super`

The reason we can call `new F` before on line 3 before line 7 is because line 7 set's

`f.__proto__.constructor === Super` where as `f.constructor` is already `Sub`. basically line 7 is cleaning `Super` up and shouldn't effect `Sub` at all because you should never call `.__proto__.constructor` in real code.

This particular function explicity does not call `Super` as function but only make's sure that objects constructed through `Sub` have `Super.prototype` in their chain.

Comment: Actually on line 3 sub.__proto__ is foo, so says Chrome console... Which is the thing that troubles me..

Comment: @bliof see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/mKCPj/) All the assertions hold true like I said.

Comment: @Raynos As far as I know when a property is searched for, it starts with the current object and if it is not there, it goes to the [[Prototype]] but here there is not a connection(or I cannot see one) between subClass's [[Prototype]] and the superClass.

Comment: @bliof `sup.__proto__.__proto__ === Super.prototype`. and `sub.__proto__ === Sub.prototype` There both in the chain

Comment: @Raynos Super.prototype is the default Object, it is not the superClass, is it?

Comment: @bliof depends what's in Super.prototype. `extend(a,b)` then `Super.prototype === b.prototype`

Comment: @Raynos And if b is function(){this.baz=10;} then it will be Object. But that means that if I want to access baz from an instance of a, it will search first a and then Object, and it will skip b. But this is not happening and it finds it. Why?

Comment: @bliof your using the function wrong. `b` is never called `b.prototype.baz` is accesible. the constructor `b` is never called so `this.baz = 10;` is never called.

Comment: @Raynos Well it is called when I create an object. But I think that I understand what this function does. It allows me to access the properties created with the prototype property. And when I create the object the superclass.constructor.call(this); gives me access to the public properties in the superclass. 10x a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
function extend(subClass, superClass) {

    // create a new empty function
    var F = function() {}; 

    // set the prototype of that function to prototype object of the superclass
    F.prototype = superClass.prototype;

    // now set the prototype of the subClass to a new instance of F
    // this is done so that subClass.prototype.foo = does not affect
    // superClass.prototype.foo
    // if you don't do this, changes to one subClass will affect superClass and all
    // other subClasses of superClass
    subClass.prototype = new F();
```

Note: `subClass.prototype = new superClass()` would call the constructor and use the returned new object as the prototype. Which would result in properties on `superClass` itself would turn up on the prototype chain (since that instance is the prototype object).

```
    // set the constructor, this indicates that 'subClass' is a function
    subClass.prototype.constructor = subClass;

    // add a property to indicate what the superClass is
    // this way one can call super methods via this.superclass.something
    subClass.superclass = superClass.prototype;

    // in case the superClass was an object...
    if(superClass.prototype.constructor == Object.prototype.constructor) {

       // change the constructor?
       // no idea why they do this here
       // this introduces a side effect to the function
       superClass.prototype.constructor = superClass;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could find an explanation about the last one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686258/javascript-inheritance-extend-function). 10x for the comment.

Comment: @bilof Ah, OK. Still makes little to no sense in an "extend" function, I would not expect that to modify the superClass.

Comment: Well, it is done to insure that the constructor call in the subClass will work.

Comment: Hey Ivo -- I saw this thread and I am curious (after a few years), if that last bit makes more sense. I personally am not understanding it fully and wondering if there is a bit more understanding with this: if(superClass.prototype.constructor == Object.prototype.constructor), and why the resetting to superClass. When would the SuperClass constructor be overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you might consider the prototype javascript library. It includes inheritance.

[Prototype Javascript Library](http://www.prototypejs.org/)

Here is an example from the prototype documentation.

```
var Animal = Class.create({
  initialize: function(name, sound) {
    this.name  = name;
    this.sound = sound;
  },

  speak: function() {
    alert(this.name + " says: " + this.sound + "!");
  }
});

// subclassing Animal
var Snake = Class.create(Animal, {
  initialize: function($super, name) {
    $super(name, 'hissssssssss');
  }
});

var ringneck = new Snake("Ringneck");
ringneck.speak();
//-> alerts "Ringneck says: hissssssssss!"

var rattlesnake = new Snake("Rattler");
rattlesnake.speak();
//-> alerts "Rattler says: hissssssssss!"
```

[Here is the documentation page](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/class/create)